# $file->original: Where does it come from?

Tags: files, redirection, testing

I am attempting to write a patch for the [Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/redirect) module that automatically creates a redirect from the old file path to the new one, whenever a file is updated.

I added a hook to redirect.module:

```
function redirect_file_update($file){
      /**
     * Creates a new redirect from old file to new one when the new one has a different URI.
     */

  if (empty($file->original)) {
    $file->original = entity_load_unchanged('file', $file->fid);
  }
  if ($file->uri !== $file->original->uri) {
    $redirect = new stdClass();
    redirect_object_prepare(
        $redirect,
        array(
        'source' => file_create_url($file->original->uri),
        'source_options' => array(),
        'redirect' => file_create_url($file->uri),
        'redirect_options' => array(),
        )
    );
    module_invoke(
      'redirect',
      'object_prepare',
      $redirect,
      array(
        'source' => file_create_url($file->original->uri),
        'source_options' => array(),
        'redirect' => file_create_url($file->uri),
        'redirect_options' => array(),
      )
    );
    module_invoke('redirect', 'save', $redirect);
  }
}
```

and I verified with a `dpm()` that $file->original exists as expected when I'm working with files in the GUI.

But when I run tests it doesn't work. [According to hook_file_update() docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_update/7), it should be called whenever file_save() is called, but it appears that <strike>the code inside my redirect_file_update() is never being called</strike>, `entity_load_unchanged()` is returning the exact same object as plain old $file, and my $file objects don't have an 'original' property as far as the test knows, even after saving. Here's the testing code:

```
function setUp(array $modules = array()) {
  parent::setUp($modules);

  $this->admin_user = $this->drupalCreateUser(array('administer redirects', 'access site reports', 'access content', 'create article content', 'edit any article content', 'create url aliases'));
  $this->drupalLogin($this->admin_user);
}
  // Test whether replacement of a file redirects the old file URI to the new one.
  function testFileReplacementRedirects () {
  // Create a few test files and save them.
  $files = $this->drupalGetTestFiles('image');
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    file_save($file);
  }
  // Get a list of all the files we just created.
  $fileQuery = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $files_list = $fileQuery->entityCondition('entity_type', 'file')
    ->propertyOrderBy('fid')
    ->execute();
  // Pick out two files to use for our test.
  $test_file_one = file_load($files_list['file'][1]->fid);
  $test_file_two = file_load($files_list['file'][2]->fid);

  // Move file one to file two's URI
  $old_url = file_create_url($test_file_one->uri);
  $new_url = file_create_url($test_file_two->uri);
  $test_file_one = file_move($test_file_one, $dest = $test_file_two->uri, $replace = FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
  // Load the old module's URI and see if it redirects to the new one.
  $this->drupalGet($old_url);
  $this_page = $this->drupalGetHeaders(TRUE);
  $this->assertEqual($this_page[0]['location'], $new_url, 'Redirected from ' . $old_url . ' to ' . $new_url . '.');
  $this->assertEqual($this_page[0][':status'], 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently', 'Status: ' . $this_page[0][':status']);
}
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$file->original` is set from [file_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save/7) to make it available to `hook_file_presave()`, `hook_entity_presave()`, `hook_file_insert()`, `hook_entity_insert()`, `hook_file_update()`, and `hook_entity_update()`. It is then removed from `file_save()` before the function returns the file object to the caller.

```
// Load the stored entity, if any.
if (!empty($file->fid) && !isset($file->original)) {
  $file->original = entity_load_unchanged('file', $file->fid);
}
```

Clearly, if the file was not previously saved, `$file->original` doesn't get set.

Comment: Indeed, and that happens because `DrupalWebTestCase::drupalGetTestFiles()` doesn't create a managed file, it only copies a file into place ready to be saved. The file will be a new one every time, so no `$original` when `file_save()` is called :)

Comment: I added a file_save() after the file_update() but hook_file_update still gets a file with no original property. Shouldn't $file->original be set after a file_save(), and different from $file after a change and a second file_save()?

Comment: Never mind, I had other bugs. Your answer was very helpful.