# Programmatically save altered file

Tags: testing, files

As I mentioned in [my previous question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57854/file-original-where-does-it-come-from) I'm attempting to write tests for a patch that will, ideally, trigger the creation of a redirect if the URI of a file changes.

My patch uses [hook_file_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_update/7) which is called whenever file_save() runs.

Currently this chunk of code:

```
  // Move file to new URI
  $new_uri = 'public://qwerty.png';
  file_save($test_file);
  $test_file->uri = $new_uri;
  file_save($test_file);
```

This calls my hook and creates the redirect, but the redirect fails because `drupalGet($new_url)` returns a 404.

`file_save()` returns the error, `filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for public://qwerty.png`.

I've tried `file_save()` on URIs that linked to existing files, which gives an error, I've tried it on not-yet-extant URIs (as above), which gives an error, and I've tried `file_move()`, which doesn't call `hook_file_update()`.

How can I programmatically change the URI of a file and trigger `hook_file_update()` inside a test?

Comment: It's probably just a typo in the question but are you calling `drupalGet($new_url)` or `drupalGet($new_uri)` (with an `i`)?

Comment: I've tried both. But I know from stepping through with xdebug that the node_save() is failing so neither will ever work. Any by "both" I mean `$test_file->uri` and the output of `file_create_url($test_file->uri)`

Comment: Have you tried invoking the same code outside of the test environment? i.e. with a file that you know definitely exists and can't return a 404? It would help to work out if the problem is within the test environment or the patch logic

Comment: BTW this is really interesting, if you're able to upload the full module somewhere I'd be happy to have a play around and see if I can work it out. Can't promise anything but you never know I might get lucky :)

Comment: I haven't tried it outside of a test (yet) but I have tried it with a file I know exists and doesn't return (on its own) a 404. That creates separate issues with file_save() because it doesn't want to use an already-in-use uri. The earlier question linked in the OP contains the entirety of my modifications to the redirect.module and redirect.test files (one custom  function on each), if you want to cut, paste, and try it out.

Comment: Trying it with the uri of an already-extant managed file causes `PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'public://docnotes_1.txt' for key 'uri'`

Comment: BTW This happens in both the test environment and a non-test sandbox now.

Comment: Cool that's something solid to go on, I've got some stuff do now but I'll take a look later on tonight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up getting around this was:

1. Upload my file as an unmanaged file at the new URI
2. `$test_file->uri = $new_uri;`
3. `file_save($test_file);`
4. `file_unmanaged_delete($old_uri);`

It didn't like it when I used a URI that was not yet in existence, nor one that was already in use by a managed file, but using one that goes to an unmanaged file seemed to work fine.